# Jenkins and JUnit annotations

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jenkins

I´m having some issues with my test suite and Jenkins.

My TestSuite looks simply like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { CompanyRepositoryTest.class,
StudentRepositoryTest.class })
public class ServiceTestSuite {}
```

Running this test suite on localhost works like a charm, and a total of 7 tests show as successful. However when the test suite is run by Jenkins, it says that no tests could be found:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.example.suite.ServiceTestSuite
```

I´m assuming that this has something to do with the annotations not being picked up by Jenkins. Can I do something to rectify this problem?

EDIT: 
This is the test part from our Ant build.xml.

```
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" >
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="test.ibm.teknikspranget.suite.ServiceTestSuite" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </junit>
```

So we´re actually trying to run the testsuite from Ant. 
Should we rather run each individual test? It looks like we´re running Ant 1.8.2 with Jenkins, so that shouldn´t be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're running this as a JUnit 3 test, not a JUnit 4 test. You can tell this because the junit.framework.* classes are JUnit 3, but the org.junit.* classes are JUnit 4. Your error message is:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.example.suite.ServiceTestSuite
```

If you run the tests with a JUnit 3 runner, then it will look for a method called `suite()` in your TestSuite, it won't use the annotations. You need to run it with a JUnit 4 test runner, such as `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` or similar.

How to fix this depends upon how you're invoking it in Jenkins. If you're running ant, use a version later than 1.7, and it should work.

If you're using maven, using a version of the JUnit library > 4 should work, try 4.11. If this still doesn't work for some reason, you can force the provider to be junit 4 by adding the following to your pom:

```
<plugins>
[...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
[...]
</plugins>
```

This is from: [Surefire: Using JUnit](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html).

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll look into this first thing tomorrow. We're using Ant, so I guess looking at the version is the first step.

Comment: It´s workning! Jenkins was configured to use the "Default" Ant version, whatever that means. By forcing it to use 1.8.2 we got the tests running again!